# How to submit long time jobs on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

I have set up an Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04), and I want to run some code compiled by 
gcc, my problem is that, if my code runs for a long time (2-4 weeks), how can I submit a job to my instance and monitor the job status? I want it to work just like I am submitting a job to a cluster managed by e.g. sun grid engine.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: you could publish job status to an external queue like SQS or SNS and monitor there

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments exchange, you are looking for nohup. e.g. `nohup ./a.out &` and your process will run in the background: linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command

Comment: You'll probably want to make your question more specific for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My problem is that, e.g., I have a binary `a.out` generated by `gcc`, if I do `./a.out` to run this code, it may take weeks to finish, however I will not be able to log out of my terminal. What I want is that I can run my code while I am still able to log out of my instance and later can log in check the progress of my running code.

Comment: Ah, you are looking for `nohup` e.g. `nohup ./a.out &` and your process will run in the background: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I want. If you can edit your main reply, I will accept it as the answer. I don't know how to accept a comment as the answer.